# Permitir acesso da Câmera e do Microfone para um WebView pelo Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, streaming

Eu criei um aplicativo **webRTC** que me permite fazer **streaming** de audio e video via usando javascript, agora eu preciso que pelo meu **Android** eu consiga acessar atráves de um app que estou desenvolvendo.

Estou usando um [WebView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/web_view/) para carregar a URL no aplicativo, porém parece que o **WebView** está bloqueando o acesso à **Camera** e **Microfone** do celular. Já tentei várias maneiras de solucionar este problema, mas nada resolveu isto.

**Observação**: O **streamming** funciona corretamente no navegador do **Android**, porém aparece uma menssagem pedindo permição de acesso da câmera e do microfone.

AndroidManifest xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="LexLoco.LexLoco" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.voicemail.permission.READ_VOICEMAIL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
    <application android:label="LexLoco"></application>
</manifest>
```

Código em C#

```
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            EditText txturl = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
            txturl.Text = URL;

            WebView webV = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewer);
            WebSettings webSettings = webV.Settings;

            webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webSettings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            webSettings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;

            webV.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            button.Click += delegate {
                webV.StopLoading();
                webV.LoadUrl(txturl.Text);
            };
```

Tentei usar a classe PermissionRequest, porém ele está gerando o seguinte erro:

[image: Linha de código com erro]
[image: Error List]

Minha tentativa foi a seguinte:

```
            WebChromeClient mWebChrome = new WebChromeClient();
            PermissionRequest request;

            mWebChrome.OnPermissionRequest(request.Grant(request.GetResources()));

            webV.SetWebChromeClient(mWebChrome);

            button.Click += delegate
            {
                webV.StopLoading();
                webV.LoadUrl(txturl.Text);
            };
```

Finalmente consegui entender um pouco do `OnPermissionRequest`, porém quando inicio o APP apresenta o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o meu código atual:

```
        string URL = "https://www.onlinemictest.com/";
        PermissionRequest req;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            EditText txturl = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
            txturl.Text = URL;

            WebView webV = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewer);
            WebSettings webSettings = webV.Settings;

            webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webSettings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            webSettings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;

            WebChromeClient mWebChrome = new WebChromeClient();
           try
            {
            mWebChrome.OnPermissionRequest(req);
            }
            catch(System.Exception ex)
            {
                alertShow(ex.Message);
            }

            webV.SetWebChromeClient(mWebChrome);
            button.Click += delegate
            {
                webV.StopLoading();
                webV.LoadUrl(txturl.Text);
            };
        }
        public void OnPermissionRequest(Android.Webkit.PermissionRequest request)
        {
            try
            { 
            req = request;
            request.Grant(request.GetResources());
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                alertShow(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        public void alertShow(string msg)
        {

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.SetMessage(msg);
            alert.Show();
        }
```

Por favor me ajudem, estou apanhando feio aqui!

Comment: Eu não vi as Tags, sorry. Irei ver se acho algo para complementar a resposta.